# Upgrade from Debian Buster to Bullseye - Operation was interrupted before it could finish

Tags: linux, debian

While I was upgrading `apt full-upgrade` I got this in the last line: `W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish`

See the full output of the last part before the "warning"

What does it mean? Was the upgrade completed successful or?

Have tried to `dpkg --configure -a` but nothing is configured

```
...
Creating config file /etc/libreoffice/registry/res/fcfg_langpack_en-US.xcd with new version
rmdir: removing directory, '/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/registry'
'/usr/lib/libreoffice/share/registry' -> '/etc/libreoffice/registry'
Setting up libboost-locale1.74-dev:amd64 (1.74.0-9) ...
Setting up libboost-graph-parallel-dev (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libopencv-videoio4.5:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libboost-coroutine1.74-dev:amd64 (1.74.0-9) ...
Setting up libboost-coroutine-dev:amd64 (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libopencv-videoio-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libboost-log-dev (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libreoffice-core (1:7.0.4-4+deb11u1) ...
Setting up libboost-fiber-dev:amd64 (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libopencv-superres4.5:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-videostab4.5:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-superres-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libboost-locale-dev:amd64 (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libboost-context-dev:amd64 (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libboost-type-erasure-dev:amd64 (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libboost-all-dev (1.74.0.3) ...
Setting up libopencv-highgui-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-features2d-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up python3-uno (1:7.0.4-4+deb11u1) ...

Creating config file /etc/libreoffice/registry/pyuno.xcd with new version
Setting up libopencv-calib3d-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-objdetect-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-videostab-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-stitching-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-contrib-dev:amd64 (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Setting up libopencv-dev (4.5.1+dfsg-5) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.9.4-2) ...
Processing triggers for dbus (1.12.20-2) ...
Processing triggers for shared-mime-info (2.0-1) ...
Processing triggers for libgdk-pixbuf-2.0-0:amd64 (2.42.2+dfsg-1) ...
Processing triggers for mailcap (3.69) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.140) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-5.10.0-13-amd64
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.17-2) ...
Processing triggers for libglib2.0-0:amd64 (2.66.8-1) ...
Setting up gnumeric (1.12.48-1+b2) ...
Processing triggers for dictionaries-common (1.28.4) ...
Processing triggers for munin-node (2.0.67-3) ...
Processing triggers for php8.1-cli (8.1.4-1+0~20220320.14+debian11~1.gbp16e58c) ...
Processing triggers for php8.1-fpm (8.1.4-1+0~20220320.14+debian11~1.gbp16e58c) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.31-13+deb11u3) ...
W: Operation was interrupted before it could finish
```

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if you press control-C while the upgrade is running.

First try to clean up any inconsistent state:

```
dpkg --configure -a
apt-get -f install
```

Then make sure that the upgrade completed:

```
apt update
apt full-upgrade
```

And of course if you get more error messages from any of these commands, stop and try to understand and resolve them before moving to the next step.

Comment: I didn't press `C+CNTRL`.. have not done what you said and nothing was updated/installed.. but everything seems to work